# Do I need to use invokeLater() for addFocusListener methods?

Tags: java, swing, focus, invokelater

I'm going through source code of large `Swing` GUI application.
And I've noticed when they want to do something in case `focusGained(Focus evn)` or `focusLost(Focus evn)` they always use `invokeLater()`.

Example:

```
yourTextField.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
                public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                            yourTextField.selectAll();              
                                    }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Why `invokeLater` is needed here?

Comment: because Focus is pretty asynchronous and invokeLater moving code line xxx.selectAll(); to the end of EDT

Comment: @mKorbel the comment should be the answer

Comment: @mKorbel, thanks! but I can't understand what does mean focus is asynchronous, and why in this case selectall should be moved to end of EDT?

Comment: Focus is based on peers from Native OS, then is heavy task, this event could be executed in any of part of items in EDT (simple queue), 1st., last, any, then selectAll() can/could/will be executed before focusGained is executed to the GUI (somehow expired as nonsence in EDT qeue), because this JTextField currently hasn't Focus, nor active Caret, invokeLater quite good guarantee that event is moved to the end of queue, the same way I'm suggest to use invokeLater for events from Document (e.g. DocumentListener/Filter)

Comment: is mentioned in official Oracle tutorial - [How to Use the Focus Subsystem - Timing Focus Transfers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#transferTiming), focus is very lazy